# Splits the given node chain (linked list) in half, returning the second half

Tags: python

I would like to Splits the given node chain(linked list) in half, returning the second half.
        If the given chain has an odd length, the extra node is part of
        the second half of the chain.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Is this homework? 

Answer (score 0):

I wont do your homeworks but here are some things that can help you:

- What is the length of the chain (to know where to stop)
- How can I find the length of the chain
- How can I use that information to stop on the correct node
- Once I am there, what do I return, what am I doing ?
- Is it correct ? I should test it to be sure.
- Success !!!